# How to save and read output of read_html as an RDS file?

Tags: r, rvest, xml2

Objects can be saved and read like so

```
# Save as file
saveRDS(iris, "mydata.RDS")

# Read back in 
readRDS("mydata.RDS")
```

But this doesn't seem to work for objects made with `xml2::read_html()`

#### Example

```
library(rvest)
someobject <- read_html("https://stackoverflow.com/")
saveRDS(someobject, "someobject.RDS")
```

Which creates a file, but not as expected
i.e.

```
readRDS("someobject.RDS")
Error in doc_is_html(x$doc) : external pointer is not valid
```

What's going on and what's the simplest way of saving an html object so that it can be loaded back in with minimal code/fuss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `write_xml` and `read_html` from `xml2` package

```
before <- read_html("https://stackoverflow.com/")
xml2::write_xml(before, "someobject1.xml")
after <- xml2::read_html("someobject1.xml")
```

However, `identical` returns `FALSE`

```
identical(before, after)
#[1] FALSE
```

but the query on both of them seem to return the same result

```
library(rvest)
before %>%  html_nodes("div")
after %>% html_nodes("div")
```

Answer (score 7):

To answer "what's going on": `saveRDS` is trying to serialize the object being saved. Here, the object `someobject` is a list with elements `someobject$doc` and `someobject$node`. The type of the elements is `externalptr` (external pointer), which means they reference a C data structure held in memory. When external pointers are serialized, the reference is lost. Hence the error "external pointer is not valid".

You could serialize `someobject` using `as.character()` and pass that to `saveRDS`:

```
saveRDS(as.character(someobject), "someobject.RDS")
```

Then recreate the object using `readRDS` and `read_html`:

```
someobject <- read_html(readRDS("someobject.RDS"))
```

But it's easier to use `write_html()` as others suggested.

Some discussion [in this Github issue thread](https://github.com/r-lib/xml2/issues/65).

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know the methods using `XML` and `RDS` files seem to be off by the same number of characters. I did a comparison and it seems like the differences between the original and the loaded version are in the body nodes.

```
url <-  "https://stackoverflow.com/"
html <- read_match(url)
html_node(html, "body")  %>% html_text() %>%  unlist() -> OBT
nchar(OBT)
```

28879

```
xml2::write_xml(html, "someobject1.xml")
html_node(html, "body")  %>% html_text() %>%  unlist() -> BT1
nchar(BT1)
```

28893

```
html   %>% toString %>% saveRDS(., "someobject.RDS")
after2 <- readRDS("someobject.RDS") %>% read_html
html_node(html, "body")  %>% html_text() %>%  unlist()-> BT2
nchar(BT2)
```

28893

This shows that the two loaded objects have the same number of characters.
If we remove a "\n" characters from all text objects the number should be the same.

```
BT1 %>% str_remove_all(.,"\n") %>% nchar(.)
```

27733

```
BT2 %>% str_remove_all(.,"\n") %>% nchar(.)
```

27733

```
OBT %>% str_remove_all(.,"\n") %>% nchar(.)
```

27733

Comment: Nice investigation, can you provide the results of the code in the bottom block?

Comment: I added to results, and I added the url because the results depend on the URL.

Comment: Interesting. Looks like `write_xml()` might add those line breaks. You might be able to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58898098/5783745) to see if there's a pattern to where the `\n` characters are being inserted?

Comment: I had a quick look, and it seems to do with the layout. For example at the bottom of the page is table with four columns: Stack overflow, Products, Company and Stack Exchange Network. If you click on the bottom one on of the fourth column(Others), and the click Technology. Everyone of the column headers (except the most left one)  will have an added "\n".

Answer (score 0):

Use `toString()` to convert `xml_document` class to `character` before saving, like so

```
library(rvest)
someobject <- read_html("https://stackoverflow.com/")

someobject  %>% toString %>% saveRDS(., "someobject.RDS")
newobject <- readRDS("someobject.RDS") %>% read_html
```

Note that these objects are not perfectly identical (I am not sure why).

```
identical(someobject, newobject)
# [1] FALSE
```