# Compare two strings and look for differences and display them for easy viewing in R (similar to git diff)?

Tags: r, stringr

Suppose I have two rather long (>100k character) strings which are mostly identical but differ in some locations.

Git has the concept of a 'diff', which shows only the differences between two (text) files.

Is there anything similar in R, where I can provide two strings and have it return a very 'human readable' excerpt showing only the differences for easily and clear visual inspection?

#### Desired output

Preferably a simple function call that accepts two (similar) strings as arguments, looks for differences between those two strings, and shows only the parts of the strings that differ, side by side, in either the R console or plot pane.

```
some_function(first_string, second_string)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a diff viewer package:

```
install.packages("diffobj")
library(diffobj)
diffObj(first_string, second_string)
```

Comment: You know an easy way to then output them into a reproducible example?  E.g. using `reprex` package...?

Comment: @BryanShalloway what happens if you use the above code in the reprex?

Comment: Package maintainer posted way of doing reprex on Twitter: https://twitter.com/BrodieGaslam/status/1258573421488848897?s=19

Comment: @BryanShalloway very nice, thanks for investigating/sharing

Comment: Also check out the new waldo package.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way of doing this using `waldo` package that has been recently created.

```
library(waldo)
library(tidyverse)

a <- "Y2xpZW50X2lkOjRjNDY1OGM1NzM"
b <- "Y2xpZW50X2lkOjRjNOY1OGM1NzM"
compare(a %>% str_split(pattern = ""),
        b %>% str_split(pattern = ""))
```